# How to pause processing code till the form hides in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am using windows forms.

I have `form1` and `form2`, I show and hide `form2` from `form1` as following:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    private void button_showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        frm2.Show();

        //I want to show the following message once form2 hides:

        MessageBox.Show("Form2 is hidden. Continue processing next line of code");

    }
}
```

In form2:

```
private void button_HideForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      Hide();  

    }
```

When I run the above code and show `form2`, `form2` shows up with the `messageBox` at same time. I know it is because when using `Show()` method it does not hold the program flow and continue executing next lines of code while using `ShowDialog()` holds the program flow till you close the child form.

What I want to do is ( I do not want to use `ShowDialog()`) : I want to show `form2` and when you finish using it and hide it I want to display the above message (in `form1`) when `form2` hides.

Anyone knows how can I do that? Thank you alot.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `ShowDialog()`? It's probably the easiest solution given your scenario.

Comment: @ Martin Parkin . I know. because I have Ms MapPoint on form2 and using ShowDialog() causes mappoint to fail and I have to use show() instead.

Comment: You are writing very buggy code, you can't really learn proper Winforms programming by trial and error.  Be sure to read an introductory book or a *really* good tutorial.  Such a book will certainly teach you about the FormClosing event and how to avoid creating UI with entirely too many windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook the Form's VisibleChanged Event, your code will then get fired when the Forms visibility changes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    private void button_showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(this.FormVisibilityChanged);
        frm2.Show();
    }

    private void FormVisibilityChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       frm2.VisibleChanged -= new EventHandler(this.FormVisibilityChanged);
       MessageBox.Show("Form2 is hidden. Continue processing next line of code");
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to place form2 instance inside button_showForm2_Click . can we avoide that? thank you

Comment: The creation of the frm2 instance was placed next to the event handler hookup for illustration. I've adjusted the code to show now an explicit unhook of the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement it in this way

Form1:

```
private void button_showForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.frm2 = new Form2(this);
    this.frm2.Show();
}

public void ShowMessage()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Form2 is hidden. Continue processing next line of code");
}
```

Form2:

```
public Form1 _Form1 { get; private set; }
public Form2(Form1 _Form1) { this._Form1 = _Form1; }

private void button_HideForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    this._Form1.ShowMessage();
}
```